# If you have a gas with $n$ particles, can you model this as a random walk of a single particle in $3n$-space?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, stochastic-processes

If you have $n$ particles in a box that undergo diffusion, this is basically a random walk of $n$ particles. Can this exactly be modeled by a single random walk in $3n$ space? Does the variance of that single random walk correspond to the variance of the particles in the box? Or is there no one-to-one analogy?

If this is true, does someone have a good introduction to the mathematics of random walks in physics for a gas?

**My specific question**
If you have $n$ random walkers in $3$ dimensions, is it equivalent to say that you have one random walker in $3n$ dimensions?

Comment: When you say "particles in a box" do you mean free particles with Hamiltonian $H=\sum_i \vec{p}^2_i/2m$? Diffusion is the macroscopic description of microscopic random walks, therefore, your question seems a bit tautologic.

Comment: I don't know what a hamiltonian is. What I specifically mean is that if you have $n$ randomwalkers in $3$ dimension, is it equivalent to say that you one $1$ random walker in $3n$ dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

> My specific question If you have n random walkers in 3 dimensions, is it equivalent to say that you have one random walker in 3n dimensions?

I would say no. Some properties of the random walk are dimension-dependent in a way that cannot be absorbed by changing the number of particles. For example, the first passage time scales with the dimensions as $P^{1st}\sim t^{-\frac{d}{2}}$ . Since the dependence on $d$ in this quantity cannot be absorbed with a constant, nor "balanced" changing the number of particles, I would say that you cannot proceed with the mapping that you propose.

> If this is true, does someone have a good introduction to the mathematics of random walks in physics for a gas?

I don't know if they treat the case of the gas with random walks, but in "*Krapivsky, P. L., Redner, S., & Ben-Naim, E. (2010). A kinetic view of statistical physics. Cambridge University Press.*" they show how to compute quantities such as the mentioned first passage time on random walks having into account the role of dimensionality.